# Apache Thrift RejectedExecutionException

Tags: multithreading, thrift

My application consists of PHP client and Java backend wired by Apache Thrift, and I faced with problem with Thrift thread pool.
In case I run PHP tests which send requests via Thrift to backend I get an exception

```
TSocket: timed out reading 4 bytes from localhost:34567
```

And at the same time I see the following in logs on Java side:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess@17a0d6f rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@80080[Running, pool size = 50, active threads = 50, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

So from my point of view it means that single-threaded synchronous PHP application uses all the configured threads (50), and it's strange.
I use Apache Thrift 0.9.0, PHP 5.4.13 and Java 1.7.0_45

Java server code:

```
public class ThriftServer implements TransportServer {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThriftServer.class);

    private final TServer server;
    private final SprootService service;
    private final int port;

    public ThriftServer(Integer thriftPort) throws IOException, ThriftException,    ConfigurationException, ConfigValidationException {
        this.service = new SprootService();
        this.port = thriftPort;
        try {
            TProcessor processor = new TSprootService.Processor<SprootService>(service);
            TServerSocket socket = new TServerSocket(port);
            TBinaryProtocol.Factory protocolFactory = new TBinaryProtocol.Factory(true, true);
            ThreadPoolServerArgs targs = new ThreadPoolServerArgs(socket, processor, protocolFactory, 5, 50);
            this.server = new TThreadPoolServer(targs);
        } catch (TTransportException tte) {
            throw new ThriftException("Exception has occured during attempt to create Thrift server on port " + port, tte);
        }
    }

    public void start() {        
        logger.info("Thrift server is started on port " + port);
        System.out.println("Thrift server is started on port " + port);
        server.serve();
    }
}
```

PHP client code:

```
class SprootClient {

    private $thriftClient = null;
    private $mappersRegistry = null;
    private $tSocket = null;

    public function __construct($host, $port) {
        $this->thriftClient = $this->initThriftClient($host, $port);
        $this->mappersRegistry = new MappersRegistry();
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->tSocket->close();
    }

    private function initThriftClient($host, $port) {
        settype($port, 'integer');
        $this->tSocket = new TSocket($host, $port);
        $this->tSocket->setRecvTimeout(3000);
        try {
            $this->tSocket -> open();
            $protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($this->tSocket);
            return new TSprootServiceClient($protocol);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new SprootClientException($e->getMessage()." ".$e->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }

    private function getThriftClient() {
        return $this->thriftClient;
    }

    public function put($cacheName, $key, $domainObject) {
        if ($domainObject == null || $key == null) {
            throw new SprootClientException("Both key and value cannot be null or empty");
        }
        try {
            $mapper = $this->mappersRegistry->getDomainMapper($cacheName);
            $dataObject = $mapper->toTDataObject($domainObject);
            $this->getThriftClient()->put($cacheName, $key, $dataObject);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new SprootClientException($e->getMessage()." ".$e->getTraceAsString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could there be a relation to [this problem over here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-692)?

Comment: Yes I saw this JIRA ticket, but it's about single server and multiple clients, but in my case there is just one server and one client. And I surprised with exception message which contains "active threads = 50, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0", so what do these threads do if there are no tasks in pool?

Comment: I don't know where the threads are coming from, it's your code. Speaking about code, could you show the relevant parts for the Thrift server stack setup? Maybe this tells us more ... and maybe the problem *is* indeed related?

Comment: I've updated question with Java and PHP code

Comment: You use a `TThreadPoolServer`. What do you think will this server do? And that scenario looks similar to me to what [THRIFT-692](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-692) is all about. Still a different problem?